# How to stop Storyboard in WPF?

Tags: wpf, storyboard

I have an animation.
But I can't stop it.
Because storyboard repeat behavior property is "Forever".
How can I stop the animation from code behind?

Here is my XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="loadingAnimation" x:Key="LoadingAnimation" RepeatBehavior="Forever" SpeedRatio="1" AutoReverse="True">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames x:Name="doubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="pathListBox">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="293.73">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <BackEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="560.097"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: There already was a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623601/stop-wpf-animation-storyboard-begin-in-xaml-but-stopping-it-in-codebehind) before. Chek it out, it can work for you too.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I'm trying this code now.

Comment: @MLE was your question answered?

Answer (score -1):

Here's how you can do:

```
Storyboard storyboard = (Storyboard)Resources["LoadingAnimation"];
storyboard.Stop();
```