# How to Stop Storyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard

I am trying to stop storyboard with `mystoryboard.stop();` But unfortunately it is not working neither it gives any error

```
Storyboard hours;
Storyboard minutes;
Storyboard seconds;

private void setStoryBoards(){
   hours = (Storyboard)this.FindResource("OnMouseWheel1");
   minutes = (Storyboard)this.FindResource("MinutesHighlighting");
   seconds = (Storyboard)this.FindResource("SecondsHighlighting");
}
private void HourStoryBoard()
{
    minutes.Stop(this);
    seconds.Stop(this);              
    this.BeginStoryboard(hours);
}
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   setStoryBoards();
   HourStoryBoard();
}
```

I want to stop other 2 animations before playing another one

**Note:** storyboard animation is created using Ms Blend and exist on `<windows.resources>`
Animation is playing fine but not stopping
Each animation is set on storyboard to play 5 times

Comment: Refer to `Timothy Groote's` answer from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623601/stop-wpf-animation-storyboard-begin-in-xaml-but-stopping-it-in-codebehind question

Comment: I am new to wpf and i didn't see any difference in my code and Timothy Groote's code could you please tell me why my code is not working

Comment: you may not be able to stop a storyboard which is not playing or started.

Comment: consider both 2 animation is started now I want to stop them after playing 3rd one

Answer (score 1):

You may not be able to stop a Storyboard, but you can change the VisualState that contains it and start a new Storyboard. Try creating a [Custom VisualState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330302%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#defining_the_visual_structure_and_visual_behavior_of_a_control_in_a_controltemplate). That may do the trick.

**[XAML]**

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
   <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CustomStates">
      <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
      <VisualState x:Name="State1">
         <Storyboard>{STORYBOARD 1 HERE}</Storyboard>
      </VisualState>
      <VisualState x:Name="State2">
         <Storyboard>{STORYBOARD 2 HERE}</Storyboard>
      </VisualState>
   </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

**[C#]**

```
private void UpdateStates(bool useTransitions)
{
   if (IsState1)
   {
       VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "State1", useTransitions);
   }
   else if (IsState2)
   {
       VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "State2", useTransitions);
   }
}
```

Comment: I will try this method after some time