# WPF Storyboard Completed Event

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm experiencing a problem where the I am unable to issue a Stop() command to a Storyboard in the Completed event.

For example

```
private void ShowStandbyGrid()
{
    StandbyGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    Storyboard sbFadeIn = this.FindResource("StandbyGridFadeIn") as Storyboard;

    sbFadeIn.Completed += (s, a) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Completed Event Fired");
        sbFadeIn.Stop(this);    //<-- This does not cause the storyboard animation to stop
    };


    sbFadeIn.Begin(this, true);
}
```

I can see the event is firing, however it doesn't seems want to stop the Storyboard Animation.

Because of this problem, every time when doing something to the UI, this animation will run continuously. I believe it is because the animation never got stopped.

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE 1**

Here's the xaml for the storyboard

```
    <Storyboard x:Key="StandbyGridFadeIn">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="StandbyGrid">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

**UPDATE 2**
OK, after 8+ hours of testing and trying, I still have no ideas why it is not working. However, here are several facts (or problem/discovery)

1. I created a button to run the storyboard in reverse direction. The storyboard executed as expected (the inverse of StandbyGridFadeIn, so more like FadeOut). However, after it is performed, the StandByGridFadeIn automatically executed again without any function calls. When it is done, I saw the console output fire 2 x "Completed Event Fired".
2. I output GetCurrentState(this); before the sbFadeIn.Stop(this); The output shows "Filling". I then output GetCurrentState(this); after the sbFadeIn.Stop(this);, the output still shows "Filling".
3. I did another test, I put sbFadeInStop(this); immediately after sbFadeIn.Begin(this, true); The animation stopped successfully.

I want to specifically discuss observation #2, considered that the event is fired if and only if the animation completed, the first GetcurrentState(this) should already output "Stopped". Is that correct?

Comment: How would you stop an animation that has already completed? Makes no sense to me.

Comment: xaml or it didnt happen

Comment: Maybe it's something with a RepeatBehavior="Forever"? Show us the definition of StandbyGridFadeIn

Comment: @Clemens I thought its completed as well, originally, I didn't think I need to put sb.stop() there. However, what I did was checking the sb.GetCurrentState() in the Completed event and it says "Filling" instead of "Stopped". That's what prompt me to wonder if I need to stop the storyboard manually.

Comment: Milan & Henrik, I forgot to show the storyboard xaml. I've updated the post.

Comment: It's Filling because the default FillBehavior of the DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames is HoldEnd.

Comment: Where is ```ShowStandbyGrid``` being called. When the storboard reaches the completed event it is stopped.  I'm assuming that you're calling that method more than once.

Comment: ShowStandbyGrid is called upon FormLoad.

Comment: @WorldWind An animation with the default FillBehavior of HoldEnd will always have the Filling state after completion. Calling Stop won't change this. You should probably read the online documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.fillbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Clemens, thanks for the reply. So the question here is, how can I stop the animation?

Comment: It is already stopped! Just do not start it again, or whatever you do there...

Comment: Try outputing a message to the console at the point where you begin the animation and see if that is output twice (or use a breakpoint). Also make sure something else doesn't trigger it (e.g. some event trigger from the XAML). Sometimes also it helps to step back a bit and re-examine your design in case there's some misconception on your part with how it should work. Sharing a demo project on github etc. would help

Comment: You can't stop the animation after it is completed. Can you post the entire code instead of snippets because I'm confused as to what you're implying. It's starting again because you are telling it to somewhere, somehow, in a trigger or code behind, or VisualState, or something.  If this has been resolved please post the answer also and if you just made a mistake, that's ok, we all do everyday, post that as well to be learned from.

Comment: did you have any progress with this?

Answer (score -2):

Judging from the code at
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5645796/903783

you may need to use

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, 
                  (Action)delegate() { sbFadeIn.Stop(); });
```

in recent C# you probably can just write

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, 
                  ()=> sbFadeIn.Stop() );
```

however, as others have commented below, it is unlikely to be the issue since you should be already executing on the UI thread

**Update:**

The comment by Clemens above is also a probable path to try, that is you may need to change the FillBehavior to Stop instead of the default HoldEnd

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.fillbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx

Alternative is to Remove the StoryBoard (e.g. MyStoryboard.Remove(MyControl)) as shown at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-set-a-property-after-animating-it-with-a-storyboard

There is a sample there that even shows how to remove an animation from a particular property using BeginAnimation and passing a null 2nd parameter

Comment: He doesn't need to invoke the Storyboard to the UI since it is on the UI.

Comment: that other code sample was also supposed to be executing at UI events, so maybe there's a special case with storyboards or something, doesn't hurt to try

Comment: No special case with Storyboards.  They are DependencyObjects and are always on the UI thread.

Comment: that's what I'd expect too - added some more things to try based on Clemens' comment above

Comment: It's not stopping because it's in the completed event meaning it's already stopped. I'm not sure what he's trying to stop at this point or what you're trying to solve with the answer. Maybe I'm missing something but when the TimeLine.Completed event fires it's over and can't be restarted and it's already stopped at this point. I realize this probably sounds worse than I mean it to be and admit I may be missing the point altogether in this question so forgive me in advance if I am.

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis I've tried the sb.Remove(this). It didn't do anything. I've even tried to recreate the Clock after it is removed, it still doesn't do anything. The animation will just run immediately after the storyboard had run in reverse direction.

Comment: @WorldWind Can you go ahead and post the entire related code files so that we can see them from top to bottom, including code behind.

Comment: @WorldWind when you say "in reverse direction" do you mean it does palindrome for ever? btw, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-repeat-an-animation in case it helps